# Magento admin panel loading all the time

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Today I noticed that after log in to Dashboard of Magento ver. 1.9.1.0, the page still loads. Do you have an idea what might be the problem?

See problem here:

[image: Loading page]

Comment: Which browser you are using. Check to login on another browser and tell me if you are logged in or not.

Comment: Also, make sure you have cleared your caches after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear Browser Cache and use firefox 35.0.1 latest version.
and if you still stuck go to address bar and at then end of url hit enter keyboard button all pages will be load.

Answer (score 1):

Cleare the browser cache or open the admin panel in incognito mode, It will help you to load the admin panel.